# Angular2 / ionic2 - Dynamically class instanciation

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I cope with a problem. I want to dynamically instanciate a class from its super class. 
Basically, I have an AbstractClass and several classes which inherits from this class.

Here is a working example in the Typescript playground :

```
class AbstractGreeter {
    static get(the_msg) {
        let class_name = (<any>this).name;
        // ... do other things here !
        var instance = Object.create(window[class_name].prototype);
        instance.constructor.apply(instance, [the_msg]);
        return instance;
    }
}
class Greeter extends AbstractGreeter {
    greeting: string;
    constructor(message: string) {
        super();
        this.greeting = message;
    }
    greet() {
        return "Hello, " + this.greeting;
    }
}

let second_greeter = Greeter.get("it's me");

let button = document.createElement('button');
button.textContent = "Say Hello";
button.onclick = function() {
    alert(second_greeter.greet());
}

document.body.appendChild(button);
```

This code works well in the playground, but I can't make it work in my ionic2/angular2 application.

The error is that the window[class_name] is undefined. I tried to put the hard-coded string but it doesn't seem to work the same way.

Is there a way to fix this ?

Thank you !

Julian

Answer (score 0):

You can try following approach:

- Create parent class as a provider
- Inject this class in child classes
- instantiate parent class in child class constructor

You also need to import and inject these classes to app.module.ts so that they are available within your application.

> http://mcgivery.com/understanding-ionic-2-imports/